# sending a form to different pages depending on values

Tags: php, javascript, html

I was wandering how you would go about sending a form to different pages.
If there is an error in the form, stay on the page, showing an error and if there is no error go onto another page 
here is my code

```
    <form id = "form" action = "./?page=markandfeedback" method = "post"> 

            <br>
            Mark for:
    <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar" value="Enter Student Number" style="min-width:165px;">
    <input type="button" value = 'Continue'  onclick="validate()">
        <?

    $studID = $_POST['txtChar'];
    $module2 = $_SESSION['module'];
    $ex = $_POST['exer'];
    $studerr = array();

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `student`, `modules` WHERE `studentID` = '.$studID.' AND `moduleCode` = '.$_SESSION['module'];
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
    echo $_SESSION['module'];
    if(isset($studID)){
        if($result == null){
            $studerr[] = "No Student with that ";
            print_r($studerr);
        }
    $_SESSION['student'] = $studID;
    }
echo'   <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">
function validate() {

   if('.$result.'  == null)
   {
       return false
   }
   else
   {
     return true;
   }

}   
</script>';

    ?>

</form>
```

cheers

Comment: can we see some code please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very briefly (without knowing other details):

```
if (!empty($errorMessage)) {
  echo $errorMessage;
} else {
  header("Location: http://domain.com/success.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched something about that ???

YOu can use normal php validation for error checking and 

`if(there is no error )
{
header('location: redirect2page.php')
}
else
{
show errors
}`

Comment: i have used headers somewhere else and it shows this error Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/63/9011663/html/index.php:39) in

Comment: @JohnSmith This error says you cannot use the Location header when you already printed out data. So the header() should be called before any echo / print / ... functions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do simple javascript validation in form submit if error occures it will return false so, thats remain on same page
like

function validate()
   {

```
   if(document.getElementById('elementid').value=='')
   {
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
     return true;
   }
```

just call this function on submit button click